# Syntax to run asynchronous code in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, asynchronous

I have a created a custom form validator (which is a function) that verifies in real-time (as we type in the dialog's text box) if an entry already exists in the Firestore DB or not. If it does exist, I would like to set the `isDisabled` and `condition` variables to `true`. My problem is that Firebase code gets executed asynchronously and therefore the function returns a value before the Firebase code is executed completely. I tried using `async/await` (`async` before `isClientAlreadyExists` and `await` before my firebase query) to no avail. Being new to angular, I'm having a hard time returning the correct value from the following function :

**Typescript :**

```
@Component({ templateUrl: 'dialog-addClient.html' })
export class DialogAddClientComponent implements OnInit {
  isDisabled = true;
  addClientForm: FormGroup;
  errorMatcher = new ClientErrorMatcher();
  addedClientName: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addClientForm = this.formBuilder.group({ clientName: '' }, { validator: this.isClientAlreadyExists });
  }

  // VERIFY IF CLIENT ALREADY EXISTS
  isClientAlreadyExists(form: FormGroup) {
    let condition: boolean;

    firebase.firestore().collection('GRD_clients').where('clientName', '==', form.get('clientName').value.toString().toUpperCase()).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log('DATA NOT FOUND :(');
        condition = false;
        // this.isDisabled = false;
      } else {
        console.log('DATA FOUND :)');
        condition = true;
        // this.isDisabled = true;
      }
    });


    // TRIED THE FOLLOWING (AND ADDING "async" BEFORE MY FUNCTION DECLARATION, BUT IT DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK 
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // const firestoreResponse = await firebase.firestore().collection('GRD_clients').where('clientName', '==', form.get('clientName').value.toString().toUpperCase()).get();
    //
    // if (firestoreResponse.empty) {
    //   console.log('DATA NOT FOUND');
    //   condition = false;
    //   // this.isDisabled = false;
    // } else {
    //   console.log('DATA FOUND');
    //   condition = true;
    //   // this.isDisabled = true;
    // }

    return condition ? { clientAlreadyExists: true } : null;
  }
```

**HTML :**

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add client</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  <form [formGroup]='addClientForm'>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="onInputChange($event.target.value)" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter client name" formControlName='clientName' [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher">
      <mat-error *ngIf="addClientForm.hasError('clientAlreadyExists')">
        Client already exists
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button [disabled]="isDisabled" [mat-dialog-close]="addedClientName" [ngStyle]="setAddButtonStyle()">ADD</button>
  <button mat-button style="outline: none;"  mat-dialog-close>CANCEL</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

My console successfully displays the *DATA FOUND* text the moment it finds an entry in Firestore. However, setting the `condition` variable to `true` doesn't execute on time before the `isClientAlreadyExists` function returns a value.

How can I change my condition variable value depending on the Firestore query result before returning a value from the isClientAlreadyExists function? You'll also notice I commented the `this.isDisabled =  true` line since it tells me it's undefined. What would be the correct way to set this variable's value to true depending on the query's result?

Thank you very much for you support.

Comment: You need to create an async validator, not a validator: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation

Comment: check this for async validators : https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/

Comment: Thank you both for your guidance. My problem was resolved using Async Validators. Following some research, I followed this guide as I am using Firebase : https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/async-form-validation-in-firebase-enforce-uniqueness/